# How can I make CMake find my libhunspell?

Tags: cmake, building, hunspell

I'm trying to build an app which (sort of) requires libhunspell-dev. I'm not root, so I downloaded hunspell:

```
$ wget -c http://downloads.sourceforge.net/hunspell/hunspell-1.3.3.tar.gz
```

built and installed it under `$HOME/opt/hunspell`. I also set:

```
export HUNSPELL_DIR=$HOME/opt/hunspell
export HUNSPELL_LIBRARIES=$HUNSPELL_DIR/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HUNSPELL_DIR/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$HUNSPELL_DIR/bin
```

And still, cmake tells me:

> ```
> **
> ** NOTICE ** Could not locate libhunspell. SpellChecker plugin will not be build
> ** NOTICE ** Try installing libhunspell-dev package
> **
> ```

What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set CMake variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `/your/home/opt/hunspell`. For command line it is `-D` flag (`cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path .`) and for GUI use `Add entry` button.

Comment: So, if I have a bunch of stuff under `$HOME/opt`, should I have multiple entries in that variables like in $PATH? i.e. `$HOME/opt/pkg1:$HOME/opt/hunspell` etc?

Comment: You can set it to multiple paths - just separate them with ";".

Comment: Are you sure it's a semicolon rather than a colon?

Comment: Yes, it's the syntax for CMake lists. Note that if you are setting this variable from code, you should use either `set(VAR a b c)` or `set(VAR "a;b;c")`.